# Yii 1.1 Time Dropdown List

Tags: php, list, yii

I have searched other dependent drop down list problems and I tried them but just don't work for me. In my case, the first drop down is a list of start times (i.e 7:00, 8:00 and so on until 10:00) and the second one is a list of end times (16:00 to 19:00). If I choose a Start Time of 7:00, 9 hours will automatically be added to it and the result will be displayed on the End Time drop down, so that'll be 16:00.

Here is my **VIEW**

This is my Start Time drop down:

```
<label class="col-lg-2 form-label"><b>Start Time</b></label>
<div class="col-lg-4" >
    <?php 
        echo $form->dropDownList($details, 'time_from', FWA::getTimeFrom(), array('class' => 'form-control')) 
    ?>
</div>
```

This is my End Time drop down:

```
<label class="col-lg-2 form-label"><b>End Time</b></label>
<div class="col-lg-4" >                            
    <?php 
        echo $form->dropDownList($details, 'time_to', FWA::getTimeTo(), array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'EndTimeID')) 
    ?>         
</div>
```

My **CONTROLLER** is kind of complicated and is also confidential. All I could say is that I don't have a separate controller for both Start and End Time. Its codes are just placed inside the `public function actionCreate()` in my FWController.php

I hope somebody can help me through this.

Comment: i think this is purely doable using jquery. Also, i think you also aware that Yii2 is out, good time to upgrade it

Comment: hi @onegun, as what I've said I have tried what I have searched in Google from all other forums and sites, they were also using jQuery and stuff but just doesn't work for me because I don't have a separate action for my Start and End time like what others have. And I cannot use Yii2 because this is a big project and it would take time to migrate.

Comment: i dont get the part why controller is needed in this case. you can use jquery to check the value of start_time when it is changed, then just add 9 hours to it in javascript, get the new end time, then check the corresponding value in end_time dropdown

Comment: @onegun sorry I didn't mean the jQuery for the controllers, I meant the others which are not using one. and I am not familiar to jQuery or Javascript, can you show me an example of what you mean? cause it will really help. thanks.

Comment: ok i will help if i have a time later to write some codes

Comment: I will wait. this is somewhat an urgent matter. thank you so much.